# Polymer in a Chrome packaged app

Tags: html, google-chrome-app, polymer

With the new Material Design released by Google and Polymer being one of the best, if not only, libraries to create such a design with ease, is there anyone to develop a Chrome Packaged App using the library to get the Material Design look it provides? Currently, it gets scripted block by Google's very strict CSP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out Vulcanize: http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html

It's a build tool for crushing HTML imports into a single file. It also has a `--csp` option that moves `<script>` into its own file. This will make CSP happy.

Answer (score 5):

We're working on a template for Polymer Chrome App in the Chrome Dev Editor:
https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor

I'll update this thread once the template is available. This should make Polymer dev in a Chrome app a lot easier.

Comment: That would be pretty awesome because bower and vulcanize are quite annoying

Comment: I like `Refactor for CSP` from Chrome Dev Editor. it's easy and simple to use. and work very well!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option.

If you're big fan of Dart language, you can use https://github.com/sunglim/csp_fixer package.
This package has a function to strip `<script/>` and create external js file.

Answer (score 1):

Investigating ebidel response about vulcanize, I found that **polybuild** could be even more easy if you dont want so many extra options.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/advanced#build

Also found this project on github that uses vulvanize with --csp option.
https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymerchromeapp