# Dart Polymer Paper with Chrome app - (inline script CSP issues)

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart-polymer, material-design

I am trying to use [the dart package for Paper Element](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/paper_elements), and it works well when i run it as a webpage but i got several CSP error when i launch it **as a packaged chrome app**. They're all relative to the inline script of the package, and the custom element aren't displayed:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>    core-icon.html:43

- Did anybody used the dart Paper Element successfully in a chrome packaged app?
- Is there any way to disable this csp from the manifest?

[Here is my sample project](https://github.com/Vloz/Polymer-Paper-Element-Test-ChromeApp)

Comment: Are you using the precompiled.js file? That file is generated specifically to deal with CSP issues

Comment: Also, no, it's not possible to override a Chrome app's default CSP.

Comment: @PixelElephant you mean that i need to use Dart2Js every time i want to debug my app??? Oo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymer in a Chrome packaged app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499858/polymer-in-a-chrome-packaged-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experience exactly same problem.

Short answer is  "Use Grunt vulcanize, https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-vulcanize

Vulcanize extract inline javascript to external javascript file(.js). 
How to use is here, https://github.com/polymerlabs/polymerchromeapp

Dart paper elements doesn't have inline javascript (of couse, they are ported to dart.).
But the problem is polymer core, paper elements. See https://github.com/dart-lang/paper-elements/tree/master/lib/src

They still have inline javascript. and they cause a CSP issue.

Answer (score 4):

I thought that I read that this setting was remove from Polymer but the package README still shows it

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer

```
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
    - web/index2.html
    csp: true
```

Here is the issue (not fixed)
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18011

I read a Polymer.js issue today that the HtmlImports polyfill can cause this problem but I didn't look closer.
I just tried, but wasn't able to find the disscussion.

Comment: `transformers` option seems to be used while `dart2js`-ing. then how can I fix csp issue when I run from Dartium? with a pure dart code.

Comment: For development you should be able to relax the policy expecially for localhost ressources https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy (haven't tried it myself - just googled)